# MVC 6 post method not found after publish

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dnx

After publish to destitution server form unable to post data to method inside Controller(everything works well on local and developement machine).

its returns 404 error.

this is my View Cshtml :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "login-form", @role = "form", @id = "loginform" }))
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-12 columns">
            <input type="text" name="username" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
         <div class="large-12 columns">
               <input type="password" name="password"/>
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
         <div class="large-12 large-centered columns">
               <input type="submit" class="button expand" />
          </div>
    </div>
 }
```

My js (ajax and post method):

```
var loginAction = function (form) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/Account/Login",
            data: { publicKeyString: SHA($("input[name=password]")},
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function (response) {
                var decodedString = atob(response);
                var NetToken = jQuery.parseJSON(decodedString);
                var userHash = SHA($("input[name=username]").val());
                $("input[name=username]").val(userHash);
                var hashpass = HashLoginData(NetToken.PublicKey, $("input[name=password]").val());
                $("input[name=password]").val(hashpass);
                $("form")[0].submit()

            },
        });
    }
```

and my Account Controller :

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Login(string publicKeyString)
        {       
//somecode
  return Content(Convert.ToBase64String(byteText), "text/plain");
            }


   [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(string username, string password)
        {
///some code
        }
```

when i open site with firefox and hit post, in firebug network section it returns 404 , but when i use fiddler and post data with composer (exact same method) it finds the method !

Comment: `url: "/Account/Login",` goes to the `Login` method of `AccountController` - you have shown the `Index()` method

Comment: @StephenMuecke it first calls the  "/Account/Login" (ajax-Post) and posting input[name=password] data to it, after success , it post the whole form to Controller Index with changed value.
problem is after posting form to controller it couldnt find the Index method.